# ¿ Como accedo a EJB Remoto desde distinto EAR en WebLogic 11g?

Tags: java, java-ee, oracle-11g, ejb, weblogic

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en WebLogic 11g (WebLogic 10.3.6), este servidor utiliza el JDK6, quiero acceder a un EJB Remoto desde un EAR distinto al que contiene el EJB, estoy trabajando en Eclipse Oxygen con las herramientas OEPE, mi codigo es el siguiente:

**Saludos.java** (*esta contenido en **ProbandoRemotoEAR**/**ProbandoRemotoEJB***)

```
package com.beans;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class Saludos
 */
@Stateless
public class Saludos implements SaludosRemote {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public Saludos() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public String Saludo(String nombre) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Hola " + nombre;
    }

}
```

**SaludosRemote.java** (*esta contenido en **ProbandoRemotoEAR**/**ProbandoRemotoEJBClient***)

```
package com.beans;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface SaludosRemote {

    public String Saludo(String nombre);

}
```

El siguiente es un Servlet del EAR que quiero que acceda al EJB anterior, entiendo que basicamente aca es donde esta el problema, en la manera de acceder al JNDI del WebLogic:

**Hola.java** (*esta contenido en **ProbandoRemotoWEBEAR**/**ProbandoRemoto***)

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.beans.Saludos;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Hola
 */
public class Hola extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Hola() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    Context contexto;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html><body>");

        Saludos saludos = null;
        try {
            saludos = (Saludos) contexto.lookup("SaludosRemote");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.println("<h1>" + saludos.Saludo("Gabriel") + "</h1>");      
        out.println("</body></html>");


    }
}
```

Lo que estoy haciendo para que **Hola.java** reconozca a los EJB es generando un jar de **Saludos.java** y colocando ese jar como libreria de **Hola.java**, pero en definitiva me da siempre un error 500 en el servidor, no es el primer codigo que tengo de esto, he intentado varios pero todos me dan el mismo error 500:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

El error `java.lang.NullPointerException` es porque estas accediendo al método de un objeto que no has instanciado. en este caso es la variable `contexto`. Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.beans.SaludosRemote;
import java.util.Hashtable;


public class Hola extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Context contexto;

    public Hola() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //Este trozo de código es necesario para conectarse remotamente al ejb en weblogic
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        //aqui debes colocar el host y la ip de tu weblogic
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
        //aqui debes colocar el nombre del usuario con el que te conectas a tu weblogic
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
        //aqui debes colocar la clave del usuario con el que te conectas a tu weblogic
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "weblogic1");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html><body>");

        SaludosRemote saludos = null;

        try {

            contexto = new InitialContext(env);
            // la variable que colocas en el método lookup corresponde al jndi de tu ejb remoto en weblogic
            saludos = (SaludosRemote) contexto.lookup("SaludosRemote");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.println("<h1>" + saludos.Saludo("Gabriel") + "</h1>");      
        out.println("</body></html>");

    }
}
```

Si estas consumiendo tu ejb remoto dentro del mismo dominio, no es nesesario que coloques el usuario y la clave, puedes eliminar o comentar el código:

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "weblogic1");
```

También debes tener el JAR cliente de tu ejb en el proyecto que quiere acceder al ejb remoto, como dependencia si ocupas maven o como librería en WEB-INF/lib.

Para validar el nombre de tu ejb remoto, lo puedes hacer ingresando al **arbol jndi** de tu servidor weblogic, accediendo a la consola de administración web, dentro de la consola has click en Server, AdminServer, View JNDI Tree, te aparecerá una ventana en donde se encuentran los JNDI disponibles, debes navegar y buscar el de tu ejb.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva, saludos.